# Hide scrollbar in rmarkdown code blocks

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I'm trying to hide the horizontal scroll bars that seem to occur by default when using `rmarkdown` with `code_folding` (I think you need to get the version of github).  But, I can't seem to get the CSS right, I thought it would be simply setting overflow to 'hidden'.

There are a couple of files, one with R code, one with CSS.  Example:

### test.R

```
##' ---
##' title: "Testing Overflow"
##' author: ""
##' date: ""
##' output_format: 
##'   html_document:
##'     theme: readable
##'     highlight: zenburn
##'     code_folding: show
##'     css: styles.css
##' ---
##' 
##' # Some code
##' How can I hide this scroll bar??
##'
##' --------------------------------
##--- test

library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE, cache=FALSE)

##'
```

Things I tried in

### styles.css

```
.sourceCode {
    overflow: hidden;
}

pre {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

From R console, you should be able to run

```
browseURL(rmarkdown::render("test.R"))
```

and see the following
[image]

**Edit**: the requested [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkqjg2bq/7/) for those without R.

Comment: what happens if you set `max-width` to `100%` ?

Comment: Can we see a live demo please?

Comment: why not a jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This CSS line is overriding your rules:

```
div.sourceCode { overflow-x: auto; }
```

Either get rid of it or use the same specificity for your next rule, like:

```
div.sourceCode {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```